# facebook log in plugin for wordpress?

Tags: facebook, plugins, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins

I'd like to have a facebook or alike log-in plug-in feature for my website so that my users would just user their social account to log in to my website. What would you recommend? Thanks!

PS I'm using wordpress 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Using oAuth you can achieve this. From facebook developer account you have to create an app id. Then use that app id to send the request.

Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/ It has got everything you would like to implement for social login using facebook.

Comment: Thanks MACMAN! Is oAuth the name for the plugin? I found several with oAuth name in it.

Comment: oAuth is a protocol. There are various libraries available based on this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/
here's one. compatible with wordpress 3.3. Also has a couple of advanced features for example being enabling the user to share stuff to his timeline.
Also, if you just require a simple login check this out: https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/
This plugin allows the user to sign in from any of the popular social networks into your site.

Or, if you want to code a custom functionality, you should check facebook sdk.